# How to programmatically add a dynamic style to an element created with createElement in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a programmatically created canvas element, and I want to attach a  reactive style to it.

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

//Add style

this.$refs.parentElement.appendChild(canvas)
```

Normally you would do it in a template with v-for and v-bind, but I can't do that in my case. Example:

```
<canvas :style="[someReactiveData ? { 'display': 'block' } : {}]"/>
```

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but what I did was:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.display = this.style.display
```

So I just update the style object and you can work with it the way you want, everytime you update the style property, the elementId style will update too.

If I wasn't clear enough I can reformulate my explanation.